# A negation of definition

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ a ring. We know that an ideal $I$ of $R$ is said prime if for all $a,b\in R$ $$ab\in I\Rightarrow a\in I\quad\text{or}\quad b\in I.$$

When an ideal is not prime? That is, what is the negation of this definition formally?

**EDIT**

I understood thanks to your comments that an ideal is not prime if $\exists a,b \in R$ such that $a\notin I$ and $b\notin I$. From here can I say that an ideal is not prime if for all $a,b\in R\setminus I$, $ab\in I$?

Thanks

Comment: Regarding edit! I afraid you can't

Comment: Your edit is not quite right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\exists a,b\in R$ with $ab\in I, a\notin I, b\notin I$

For example, $2\cdot3\in 6\mathbb{Z}, 2\notin 6\mathbb{Z}, 3\notin 6 \mathbb{Z},$ so $6 \mathbb{Z}$ is not a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Thanks for your ansewer. But it's corret said that $I$ is not prime if exist $a,b\in R$ such that if $ab\in I$, then $a\notin I$ and $b\notin I$, therefore if and only if for all $a,b\in R\setminus I$ $ab\in I$?

Comment: @JackJ. No, that's wrong.

Comment: and what is the correct formulation?

Comment: @Jack J , what he written is absolutely correct  ...negation of if... Then 'is not'  if ... Then not

Comment: negation of $P\implies Q$ is $P$ and $\neg Q$.   I added this in my answer too

Answer (score 4):

An Ideal $l$ is not prime if there exists $a,b\in R$ such that

$ab\in I , a\notin I $and $b\notin I$

(Note : negation of $P\implies Q$ is $P$ and $\neg Q$